# How to create a Timestamp and Geopoint instance in Firebase Emulator from browser console

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have create a mock data and performed a batch update with `firestore.batch()`. The problem is that location is saved as a `number` and time as a `string` and not as Geopoint and Timestamp instances respectively, causing my React app to crash.

I could see that only `firestore` is accessible through `window.firestore`, but not Firebase. Since Firebase isn't exported as `window.firebase`, I cannot create either Geopoint or Timestamp instance.

So, how to create a Timestamp and Geopoint instance in Firebase Emulator from browser console?

Here's a type of `doc` I'm adding to firestore

```js
const doc = {
  "company": "company-1",
  "location": [
    -72.3623, // number
    79.5748   // but, want to convert to Geopoint instance
  ],
  "time": "Fri Sep 10 1976 07:42:23 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",      // string
  "createdAt": "Mon Apr 28 2014 13:30:16 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)", // want to convert to Timestamp
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more dependable accessor path than `.Gf`:

`new firestore.app.firebase_.firestore.GeoPoint(lat, lng)`

Answer (score 1):

There's a `firebase` accessible through `window.firestore`.

So I figured a way to create Geopoint and Timestamp instance through Firestore.

You can access it through `window.firestore.Gf.firebase_`, through which you can create those both instance.

```js
const raw = // pasting from clipboard
const batch = firestore.batch()
const firebase = firestore.Gf.firebase_

const Timestamp = firebase.firestore.FieldValue().Timestamp
const GeoPoint = firebase.firestore.FieldValue().GeoPoint

raw.forEach(doc => {
  const docRef = firestore
    .collection('user')
    .doc('user-1')
    .collection('interviews')
    .doc()
  
  doc = {
    ...doc,
    time: Timestamp.fromDate(new Date(doc.time)),
    createdAt: Timestamp.fromDate(new Date(doc.createdAt)),
    location: new GeoPoint(doc.location[0], doc.location[1])
  }
  
  batch.set(docRef, doc)
})

batch.commit()
```